# Is there a way to query Google AppEngine Search API for documents where a field contains at least one of the search items?

Tags: google-app-engine

For instance, suppose we have 3 zoos in a Datastore.

- `(id=23, animals=["Horse", "Elephant", "Giraffe"]`
- `(id=42, animals=["Alpaca", "Turtle", "Panda"]`
- `(id=77, animals=["Wolf", "Alligator", "Tiger"]`

I want to query for zoos that contain AT LEAST ONE of the following animals: `"Horse", "Elephant", "Alpaca"`. I need this query to return zoos 23 and 42, but not zoo 77.

Tried so far:

- `animals: "Horse" OR animals: "Elephant" OR animals: "Alpaca"` works for smaller queries, but in the actual real life case queries constructed like that easily exceed 2000 bytes query size limit imposed by Google.
- `("Horse" OR "Elephant" OR "Alpaca") IN animals` returns 0 results.
- `animals IN ("Horse" OR "Elephant" OR "Alpaca")` returns 0 results.

Restriction: must be a fixed amount of queries, ideally a single one. A solution where the amount of queries grows with the amount of search items won't scale and will easily result in hundreds of Datastore queries per single HTTP request from a user. That is unacceptible.

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
animals: ("Horse" OR "Elephant" OR "Alpaca")
```